# Featured image upload finished hook

Tags: post-thumbnails, hooks

I'm looking for a way to hook into the process of uploading a featured image. Ideally I would want to be able to do some stuff right when the upload has finished, before the thumbnails are generated.

What I wanna do is when the image is finished uploading, the user will be presented with the possibility to [resize and crop](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) their image before it's actually set as the featured image.

Is this possible, or should I rather be thinking of a custom uploader that I use to later set the finished image as the featured image?

Answer (score 0):

There is a deault feature available on WP to crop image once you upload. You can edit the image you upload and can crop image with 
you preferences. 
[How to crop rotate scale and flip images in wordpress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-crop-rotate-scale-and-flip-images-in-wordpress/)

WordPress by default is designed to generate 3 types of cropping of any uploaded images (Media) automatically to ensure site speed with different sizes where necessary. So, with uploading the Original image there would be at least 4 files-

```
The Original File (not-cropped),
 => the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Original image resolution (unmodified)
Large,
 => the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
Medium, and
 => the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
Thumbnail.
 => the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)

Custom size 
the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  // Other resolutions
```

You can add other custom size with your preference as:
 => add_image_size() //will automatically create the versions of the images suitable for positioning in your website theme.

Using [add_image_size()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) function with your desired parameter allows you to add new size for your site. Use the function into your functions.php to add your desired image size:

Hope that helps!!